# My sql query some mistake in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dinv`.`sp_InsertCustomer`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_InsertCustomer`(
 IN vCustId varchar(120),
 IN vName Varchar(16),
 IN vMobileNumber Varchar(120),
 IN vEmail Varchar(500),
 IN vCountry varchar(120),
 IN vCity VarChar(80),
 IN vZipCode Date,
 IN vAddress VarChar(80),
 IN vRemarks Date,
 IN vCreatedBy Varchar(80),
 IN vParam Varchar(50)
 )
BEGIN
SET @type = vParam;
IF @type="Save"  THEN
 Insert into customer(CustID,Name,MobileNumber,EmailId,Country,City,ZipCode,Address,Remarks,CreatedBy,CreatedDate)
values(vCustId,vName,vMobileNumber,vEmail,vCountry,vCity,vZipCode,vAddress,vRemarks,vCreatedBy,GetDate());
ELSE
 Update  customer Set Name=vName,MobileNumber=vMobileNumber,EmailId=vEmail,Country=vCountry,City=vCity,ZipCode=vZipCode,Address=vAddress,
Remarks=vRemarks,ModifiedBy=vCreatedBy,ModifiedDate=GetDate() where CustID=vCustId;
END IF;
DELIMITER ;
```

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 23

hi i'm new to mysql and  trying  to write procedure with if else condition  but getting error so plz help..
thanks

Comment: Where does the procedure end?

Answer (score 1):

you don't have `END` statement to terminate the `BEGIN` block.

basically you have this structure

```
DELIMITER $$
-- DROP STATEMENT
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertCustomer(..parameter list..)
BEGIN
    SET @type = vParam;
    IF @type = "Save"  THEN   -- mysql accepts double quotes and single quotes
        -- INSERT STATEMENT
    ELSE
        -- UPDATE STATEMEMT
    END IF;
END $$       -- <<== lacking part
DELIMITER ;
```